Optical projector that reduces image size
I'm starting to wonder if this is not possible.
I have built a projector to project UV light, through a monochromatic mask [a black & white 2x2 film negative] onto a target. The image on the film will be about 4mm in height. I need the image on the target to be about 1mm, but adjustable from about 0.5mm up to 3mm. At each size setting, I need to be able to fine adjust to get best focus.
What am I doing? I want to engrave a very small number on jewelry to identify the jewelry in the event of theft. [yes, this is patent pending protected, so no copy cats, please]. The target will be coated with a photosensitive resist, then etched.
I can adjust the distances between light source [a 100W UV LED], film, lenses, and target as needed to give me the desired projected image. I need someone who can specify the optical system necessary to do this, as well as the required distances between everything.
I am a degreed electronic engineer, but I slept through my optics classes - I remember nothing.
If needed, I am not opposed to adding collimator lenses, a filter to restrict the UV light to a single frequency, or whatever it takes. I've hired two different people to assist with this, and both gave me garbage that doesn't even come close.
I have played with all sorts of convex, convex/plano, and concave lenses, but I can not get a usable reduced-size image. Is this just not possible with conventional optical lenses?

I guarantee you it's possible --- this is how millions of integrated circuits are made every day. You should specify the wavelength --- In the EUV range used for newer semiconductor designs, glass becomes opaque and ordinary optics don't work. But at near UV (200-300 nm, say), it shouldn't be a problem.

Considering the answerer is expected to do better work than two people you employed, should one expect to have their name attached to this patent for helping?

directed to Da Monster - Ha Ha Ha! A patent is issued for creative uniqueness. I'm sorry, but solving this problem cannot qualify, UNLESS it can be shown that what I need is impossible, and you find a solution. Given that Photon guarantees that a solution is possible, I'm afraid the patent office would not allow the inventor to include the designer of a possible part of the equipment. The patent will be for "branding" jewelry to make absolute identification possible, not for the equipment to do the engraving. BTW, I have 6 patents issued to me.

See the RP Photonics Encyclopedia and RP Photonics Buyer's Guide for information on many optical components

I find it fascinating that the patent system supports an "invention" the which is novel and yet the design of it is so industry standard that one can crowd source (Creative Commons) the design without attributing credit.

I received a patent for an aircraft entertainment system. the "system" was composed of all off-the-shelf electronic parts. The uniqueness of the invention was that people could play games, communicate, etc with other people in random seats. The fact that common ICs, transistors, resistors, etc were used is irrelevant to the patent or the invention. Here, the uniqueness is that a piece of jewelry can be positively identified, similar to diamonds being micro engraved. Except the identification has never been applied to jewelry.

BUT...... I'm seeking help on image reduction by optical means, not discussing the details of patents. That said, I am happy to help with patent issues - WITH the understanding that I am NOT a patent attorney, or any kind of lawyer, just someone with lengthy experience with writing, filing and prosecuting patents.

You need a machine called a projection aligner. This takes a macro-sized mask image and squeezes it down to micro-size, allowing tiny traces to be imaged in photoresist. This is how integrated circuits are manufactured.

Hi Niels: did a little investigation into aligners. If I understand it correctly, it wouldn't work well in my case. I am dealing with a target that can be non-linear in multiple directions. The aligner concept seems to be intended for flat-bed applications. picture a ring where it is curved in all directions.

You'd need some kind of aligner with both large working distance and great depth of field. I do not know if these exist.

I was asked about wavelength. The LEDs I've bought are called 390nm. What I do not know is their frequency bandwidth. They may emit UV on both sides of that nominal       390nm.

390 is good for exposing photoresist;  though 365 is better. they put out very little at shorter wavelengths but significant amounts in the visible violet range.

My fundamental question is how to project a somewhat smaller image than the mask image?

I do not know the name of the lens system you need.

The question is vague, but in essence if you want a magnification of 0.25, The simplest projection system is a single lens. You have the thin lens equation (24.3.1), and the equation for the magnification (24.3.2) in the Physics LibreTexts. I made a screenshot of those equations below:


d_o is the distance between the object and the lens, d_i is the distance between the image and the lens, f is the focal length of the lens, and m is the magnification. Choose a focal length, say 100mm, and a magnification of -0.25 (because a single lens will invert the image, just reverse the mask and the pattern will be upright in the image). The object or mask should be 500mm from the lens, and you'll have a 4 times reduced image at 125mm from the lens.
This is how it would look like in the OpticStudio (Zemax) software. On the left would be the mask, and on the right is an image of it, four times smaller.

For every magnification you desire, you can recalculate d_o and d_i.
This is of course the simplest projection system, but since we don't know anything else about what you want, that's the best I can do. Other things to ask yourself are, what resolution do you want to achieve? Are you projecting on a flat surface? If not, what is the geometry of the surface you are projecting onto, and is it constant? How do you illuminate the mask? Have you considered scanning a beam to create the pattern as opposed to using a mask (this is how laser machining is usually done)? It has the advantage that the magnification is controlled by the scanner of the beam, and doesn't require the movement of the lens. Search for galvanometer scanners.

I guess I know so little about optics that I do not understand where/why the question is vague. I have a UV [390nm] light source. My goal is to expose a photosensitive coated target with UV, where the image on my mask [a 2x2 slide] is larger that the image I need on the target. I would like to be able to reduce the image size anywhere from about 10% reduction to 90% reduction.

Omnistic's response looks like the most understandable I have seen, but I suspect that the most simplistic solution isn't necessarily the best one. Because I will be engraving very small characters, I need the sharpest possible image. I will be using a modified microscope to look at the image with visible light before turning on the UV to do the exposing.

It is vague because on one hand you have state of the art lithography systems that print our processors with nearly a nanometer resolution (several hundreds of million USD), and on the other hand you have that single lens (tens of USD), which could give you a resolution in the order of a few micrometers, and there's a world of solutions in between. Since you are an electronic engineer, its a bit if I asked you for the best battery possible. If I don't tell you more specifications, you'll probably have a hard time answering the question.
